# Flutter The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type

Tags: flutter, dart

I just put my bottom sheet in Widget function like this

```
  Widget earnPoints() {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setStatee) {
            return Material(
              child: Container(
                  height: height * 0.9,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(children: []),
                  )),
            );
          });
        });
  }
```

And its showing error that

The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.

I am using return also

Comment: You can't return the modelBottomSheet it;s not a widget

Answer (score 0):

also add return before `showCupertinoModalBottomSheet()`

Comment: I try but its showing this when return A value of type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be returned from the method 'earnPoints' because it has a return type of 'Widget'.

Comment: add your `showCupertinoModalBottomSheet` signature or code

Comment: If i use Future<dynamic>  instead of Widget its working fine i dont know why

Comment: Maybe because your `showCupertinoModalBottomSheet` return Future<Widget> without declaring return type that's why static analysis says its returning Future<dynamic> but actually after some time its return Wiget that why it's running

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you aren't returning `showCupertinoModelBottomSheet()`,

```
Future<Widget> earnPoints() async{
  double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  
  return showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(  /// add return here
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setStatee) {
          return Material(
            child: Container(
              height: height * 0.9,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(children: []),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      );
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: I try but its showing this when return A value of type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be returned from the method 'earnPoints' because it has a return type of 'Widget'.

Comment: When you are calling, do you call it with `await`?

Comment: Nup, but i replace Widget with Future<dynamic>  its working fine

Comment: Better to replace it with `Future<Widget>`

Comment: Tried but same error on showCupertinoModalBottomSheet if i use Future<Widget>

Comment: Have to add `async` modifier to the function.